# Is it possible for a C# application to communicate with a Kernel Driver?

Tags: c#, c++, c, kernel, minifilter

I've been wondering whether my KMDF driver is able to communicate directly with C# application and vice versa.

After a couple research, I could only find minifilter to work from a C# service, not so sure about a C# application (with regular Win32 privileges)

Is the following a correct solution...?
Kernel Driver (C) <---> DLL (C++) <---> Application (C#)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: So what does that have to do with C++ or C? Sure, the NT kernel is written mostly in C, but ...?

Comment: I've included those tags just in case someone knows whether such solution works.

Comment: check DeviceIOControl API

Comment: An example of KMDF driver written in C++ and a C# Win App communicating with it can be found here: https://delog.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/custom-usb-driver-and-app-using-winusb-and-c/

Comment: The delog you have referenced explains an example of WinUSBNet, which is limited to USBs.

Answer (score 0):

Usualy minifilter use  [FltSendMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544378(v=vs.85).aspx), not DeviceIOControl

Just make Pinvoke call for it or use wrapper